# Error installing gtop on Ubuntu 22

Tags: command-line, nodejs, npm

I just installed ubuntu on my work machine and trying to get gtop working on it. It's saying I'm missing the **node:process** package, but I'm not able to find any solutions. I figured that the easy install of npm and nodejs wouldn't have had any issues, but would greatly appreciate any guidance. Here's the steps I used to install gtop and the resulting error:

1. install npm and nodejs

`sudo apt install npm nodejs`

2. install gtop

`sudo npm install gtop -g`

And this is the error when I try to run gtop from the command line.

```
(base) octosaurus:~$ gtop
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:process'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/node_modules/marked-terminal/index.cjs
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/node_modules/blessed-contrib/lib/widget/markdown.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/node_modules/blessed-contrib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/lib/gtop.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/bin/gtop
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/node_modules/marked-terminal/index.cjs:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/node_modules/marked-terminal/index.cjs',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/node_modules/blessed-contrib/lib/widget/markdown.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/node_modules/blessed-contrib/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/lib/gtop.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gtop/bin/gtop'
  ]
}
```

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 22 in the title; but Ubuntu Core 22 cannot use `apt` or *deb* packages (is in final *beta* currently & due for release very soon). Are you sure you're using a 22 release, and not 22.04 ?  The *year.month* format products are different to the *year* or *snap* only products of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my npm and nodejs were out of date. I upgraded npm by:

`sudo npm install -g npm`

I upgraded nodejs using the instructions by dylandhall [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157):
for anyone else with the same issue: delete the new package source:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
sudo rm nodesource.list
```

update apt, fix the install, remove nodejs and the nodejs-doc packages

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove nodejs
sudo apt remove nodejs-doc
```

then use the instructions to install the latest node

in my case:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```